# Modify or update contacts using intent programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to intent to the android contact window to update or modify a user contact details.
The code below works fine, however, it does not pass the correct phone number to the android contact editor window.

This is my code

```
 private void modifyContact() {
         phonenumber="0711236763";

    mSelectedContactUri=Uri.parse(phonenumber);

    mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);


    if (mCursor != null && mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        mLookupKeyIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY);
        mCurrentLookupKey = mCursor.getString(mLookupKeyIndex);
        mIdIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        mCurrentId = mCursor.getLong(mIdIndex);
    }

    mSelectedContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(mCurrentId, mCurrentLookupKey);
    Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);

    editIntent.setDataAndType(mSelectedContactUri, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
    editIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);

    startActivity(editIntent);

    }
```

The variable `phonenumber` is the phone number for which i would like to modify or update.

Comment: why is `mCursor` null?

Comment: So should i intialize it with null, i'm really stack, i don't know how to go about it

Comment: why are you using `mCursor` if it is null?

Comment: I'm new to this, i don't know what mCursor is, can you please expand more your comment?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." it works in my code.

1.Try to position cursor by moveToFirst before reading data from it.

2.check for null-> if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {}

3.check for count-> (c != null && c.getCount() >0 && c.moveToFirst()){}

Comment: Thank you Sanneesh,i'm new to Cursor class, can you update your answer including my function? kindly