# How to use Intent to prompt deletion of contact

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I would like to prompt an Android user to delete a contact through their default contact app by passing in the contact's name.  I would like to avoid using `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` and `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS` in order to be in strict compliance with Android's privacy policy.

This was some of the code I was attempting:

```
Cursor mCursor;
        // The index of the lookup key column in the cursor
        int lookupKeyIndex;
        // The index of the contact's _ID value
        int idIndex;
        // The lookup key from the Cursor
        String currentLookupKey;
        // The _ID value from the Cursor
        long currentId;
        // A content URI pointing to the contact
        Uri selectedContactUri;


        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46823595/modify-or-update-contacts-using-intent-programmatically
        //https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics
        //https://codedocu.com/Details_mobile?d=1717&z=0&t=Android+code%3A+Lookup+a+contact+by+the+phone+number
        String[] mProjection = {ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID};
        mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + "=" + address, null, null);

        /*
         * Once the user has selected a contact to edit,
         * this gets the contact's lookup key and _ID values from the
         * cursor and creates the necessary URI.
         */
        // Gets the lookup key column index
        lookupKeyIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY);
        // Gets the lookup key value
        currentLookupKey = mCursor.getString(lookupKeyIndex);
        // Gets the _ID column index
        idIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID);
        currentId = mCursor.getLong(idIndex);
        selectedContactUri = ContactsContract.Contacts.getLookupUri(currentId, currentLookupKey);

        // Creates a new Intent to edit a contact
        Intent editIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
        /*
         * Sets the contact URI to edit, and the data type that the
         * Intent must match
         */
        //editIntent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE );
        editIntent.setDataAndType(selectedContactUri,ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
        editIntent.putExtra("finishActivityOnSaveCompleted", true);
        startActivity(editIntent);
```

When the debugger gets to

```
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null ,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME + "=" + address, null, null);
```

the code crashes with

```
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: opening provider com.android.providers.contacts.ContactsProvider2 from ProcessRecord{a527924 31476:com.rc.rentcollection/u0a221} (pid=31476, uid=10221) requires android.permission.READ_CONTACTS or android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS
```

Is it possible to prompt a user to delete a contact through their default contact application given the contact's name without requesting `android.permission.READ_CONTACTS` and/or `android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS`?  If so, please tell how to accomplish this task.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible, here's a list of the intents supported by the stock Contacts app on Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Contacts

It allows you to select (pick), view, edit or insert a contact.